# Writing the output to a different csv file column

Tags: python, csv

I have some vocabulary and their counterparts to create an Anki deck. I need the program to write the output of my code in two columns of a csv file; first for the vocabulary and second for the meaning. I've tried two codes but neither of them worked. How can I solve this problem?

Notebook content(vocab):

```
obligatory,義務的
sole,単独,唯一
defined,一定
obey,従う
...
```

First try:

```py
with open("C:/Users/berka/Desktop/Vocab.txt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    with open("C:/Users/berka/Desktop/v.csv", "w", newline="") as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=",")

        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Second try:

```py
with open("C:/Users/berka/Desktop/Vocab.txt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open("C:/Users/berka/Desktop/v.csv", "w",) as f:
        field_names = ["Vocabulary", "Meaning"]

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=field_names, extrasaction="ignore")

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Result of the first try:
[https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/696432733882155138/746404430123106374/unknown.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U29lG.png)

#Second try was not even close

Expected result:
[https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/734460259560849542/746432094825087086/unknown.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4a3F.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kevin said, Excel uses "**;**" as delimiter and your csv code creates a csv file with comma(,) delimiter. That's why it's shown with commas in your Csv Reader. You can pass "**;**" as delimiter if you want Excel to read your file correctly. Or you can create a csv file with your own Csv Reader and read it with notepad if you want to see which delimiter it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Your first try works, it's the app you're using for importing that is not recognizing the `,` as the delimiter. I'm not sure where you're importing this to, but at least in Google Sheets you can choose what the delimiter is, even after the fact.